# How to compile single class dependency in gradle outside the main project

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that contains only Selenium/TestNG test classes.  They are executed against a deployed war application.  All works fine and now I'm adding a java utility that will query the test base and print list of tests that belong to a given TestNG group.  The utility should be compiled and executed separate from the main project, as users may want to query the test base before test execution.

I added the following to build.gradle:

```
task listgroups(dependsOn:'buildUtil' ) <<{
    ant.java(classname: 'util.TestGroupScanner', fork: true,
            classpath: "src/test/java")
}

task buildUtil {
    compile {
        source = "src/test/java/util"
    }
}
```

However, when calling listgroups task, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\console-bg1>g listgroups

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
(...)

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'console-bg1'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [build_4emu7duna2isgubc1k8uts8k9
8$_run_closure6_closure11@d210ab] on root project 'console-bg1'.
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue and needless to say, haven't found an answer online so far.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `buildUtil` task, as the error suggests. The `buildUtil` declares a `compile` closure, but such closure does not exist for the default task.

Let me try to clarify what your setup is. The `util.TestGroupScanner` source is in the `src/test/java/util` directory, which you want to compile separately from other source (presumably `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`). The `buildUtil` task is supposed to compile sources in `src/test/java/util`, and the `listgroups` task executes the scanner utility on sources `src/test/java` folder.

In this case, I'd suggest you declare a new [source set](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11AE8) for your utility sources, like this:

```
sourceSets {
  util {
    java {
       srcDir 'src/test/java/util'
    }
  }
}
```

This will automatically create a compile task called `compileUtilJava` for you, that will compile those sources. I also think you'll want to include utility classes in the classpath when executing your tool, which can be retrieved by `sourceSets.util.output.classesDir`. So now your `listgroups` task will look like:

```
task listgroups(dependsOn: 'compileUtilJava' ) <<{
  ant.java(classname: 'util.TestGroupScanner', fork: true,
           classpath: "src/test/java:" + sourceSets.util.output.classesDir)
}
```

One thing I have noticed about your setup, is that `src/test/java/util` source folder is nested under `src/test/java`. Gradle will assume `src/test/java` to be the default folder for your project test, and will therefore automatically include it, and all of its children when running tests. Since you want to keep your utility folder separate from the default setup, I would recommend you put it in `src/testutil/java`, to avoid any clashes. If you do, don't forget to update the `sourceSets` setup above with the correct source path.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  I have a better understanding now of how gradle works...  You are right, I need to move util out of the test/java directory structure.  Thank you for pointing this out.  I combined your sourceSet definition with JavaExec from the other response and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with gradle, I suggest to create a specific sourceset for your util class and add a task of type JavaExec that executes this class for printing your testng groups. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
apply plugin:'java'
...
...
configurations{
    testUtilCompile.extendsFrom testCompile 
}

...
...
sourceSets{
    testUtil{
        java {
            srcDir "src/test/java"
            include "util/**"
        }
    }
}

task printGroups(type:JavaExec){
    main = "util.TestGroupScanner"
    classpath = sourceSets.testUtil.runtimeClasspath
}
```

regards,
René